# Performance based on length of "terms"

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following criteria in the query. The terms list for seen by can grow significantly large. There are also a couple of similar kind of list in "must_not" clause and those can be grow large too.

```
          {
            "terms": {
              "seen_by": [
                "54",
                "3",
                "418",
                "411",
                "1",
                "101"
              ]
            }
          }
```

What will be the performance difference if the list of terms in conditions grows or shrinks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question without knowing details about your data size, terms distribution and queries. In general, the number of terms is contributing linearly into search time. Basically, the search engine has to pull a list of documents for every term in your query. Because of this, it's typically not recommended to execute queries with very large number of terms and elasticsearch is actually limiting the number of clauses in boolean queries to 1024 (it can be changed using indices.query.bool.max_clause_count setting).

Comment: How would you do this using elasticsearch-js? Is it possible if not, how would I create and use a yml with elasticsearch-js?